# xataface how to make drop down menu

Tags: xataface

I want to know how I can make a drop down menu for a certain group of tables. An example here:

[image]

In this screen shot we can see 5 tables horizontally.

How can we transform these 5 tables to drop menu like the one menu on side control panel:

[image]

so that I can give custom name to that menu and when on hover or on click it display 5 tables name in drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arbitrary actions to the top left menu.  See this thread for details.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/xataface/tQhy6yePe1M/fL8u26hafAcJ